# Airflow installation error on mac with python3

Tags: installation, airflow

I am installing airflow with python version **3.7.3** and using commmand `pip install apache-airflow`, but I am getting the following error.
Kindly help me resolve this.

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/gn/62wd4sgd3d3153jxk1l4kv6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-x6yn4ceb/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel:
  ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/gn/62wd4sgd3d3153jxk1l4kv6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-x6yn4ceb/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall `enum34` if it is installed.

Run:

```
pip uninstall enum34
```

This is caused because of a dependency we had on Airflow.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Can you upvote and accept the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install airflow and other dependents with brew.
Brew is repository manager for mac os similar to apt-get in linux

Comment: There is no apache-airflow formula in brew as of now. The `airflow` one is a cask for the airflow app, which has nothing to do with apache airflow.